# Recreating Managed Package Scheduled Jobs

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-job

We have scheduled jobs of Managed Package. We are about to inactive the user that owns the scheduled job. For that, we need to recreate the scheduled jobs. The issue is, we cannot see the *Manage* Button next to the scheduled job.

[image]

I also tried by logging in from the user, but all I see is 'Del' button. Is there any reason why I am not able to see the Managed Button?

Comment: Manage button is nothing but just a way to change or view the existing schedule setting, you can do the same from Schedule Apex button on Apex class page as well. First delete existing job and reschedule them from there. Check if you can see this button.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But there is no way I can see which Apex Class is scheduled. I need the name of the Apex Class so that I can recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Apex Jobs" list has an "Apex Class" column that will give you the class name. Note that results only stay listed for seven days.

Alternatively, contact the managed package vendor.

Comment: Well, I found the Class Name from "Apex Jobs" list and made a pattern using the 'Completion Date'. I might be able to recreate this scheduled job. Thanks a lot @Keith